# Caching a website in iOS for offline use using Service Worker or similar

Tags: ios, caching, uiwebview, browser-cache, service-worker

Here is my code, which should load a webpage from a given URL:

```
let url = URL(string: urlString)
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
urlRequest.cachePolicy = .returnCacheDataElseLoad
webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
```

The problem is that I want to achieve the following:

- Fully cache a website's HTML/CSS/JS
- Fully load responses to clicks on hyperlinks from cache, unless an external web service needs to be accessed
- Store website's JSON data (e.g. form data) in the device and make them available offline as cookies/DB records

I don't mean building a Progressive Web App, which can come with offline functionality (but not in iOS). What I mean is adding a Service Worker to a website container (WebView or iframe) in iOS. Same origin policy is not a problem, I am able to edit the website code.

Is it possible to achieve it in iOS and possibly Android?

Comment: your question is too broad to answer in iOS

Comment: I don't mean building a Progressive Web App, which can come with offline functionality (but not on iOS). What I mean is adding a Service Worker to a website container (WebView or iframe) in iOS. Same origin policy is not a problem, I am able to edit the website.